# WSL VSCode call Windows Python Executable

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

- Context: Running python in VSCode on Windows
- Default Terminal is Bash (via WSL)
- Using WSL - Debian
- Python 3 installed on Windows, not on WSL

**I want Bash to call my Windows Python Executable when I run my python files**. I am only using WSL so I can replace cmd/powershell with bash. I do not want to install anything on WSL, I want to use existing programs on Windows (in this case Python).

However when I try to run my Python file (Clicking 'play' button) I get the error:

```sh
-bash: C:/Users/Connor/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe: No such file or directory
```

*I believe this can be solved by replacing C: with \mnt\c*

**How can I achieve this?**

[image]

Comment: replace `C:` with `/mnt/c` and it might work. Perhaps in your vscode configuration.

Comment: @fredrik, which exact setting?

Comment: That I don't know - check your settings.json. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: @fredrik thanks, though I'm starting to think what I'm attempting goes against the grain for WSL usage. Perhaps I'm better off uninstalling Windows Python and just using the WSL python instead lol

Comment: Probably. Though you can still use WSL python without uninstalling the one on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same problem as yours. I solved this by following steps.

1. Open the VSCode
2. On your left-down side, you can see the the icon that I pointed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVOzs.png) (the name in here is "Open a Remote Window")
3. Next you can see above the "Reopen Folder in WSL" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQx65.png) and clicked
4. Then you can run python with wsl and no more directory errors